# MVC Switch V without C?

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, design-patterns

I've started recently to have a closer look and Java and some of the common patterns. As to MVC, there are countless discussions as to where the line in the sand has to be drawn. But! Most of the one, I read, are quiet fruitless IMHO, as to none have any practical appliance what so ever.

So, I'm looking into the subject, because I've been asked to rewrite an old PHP-application and - if possible - to make it a 'real' application. Now, wouldn't it be nice to go for a clean architecture? I'd like to build both the web-version as well as the SWT-version with the same backend.

Question: Changing the V is clear to me, but as far as I can see, I have to either build a new controller completely or I would have to add adapters between the controllers and the views, what in turn would be the same as the controller itself, if I'd apply the same on the model-side. So, in short: is it desirable or even possible, to actually only change only the V in a real world scenario?

Hope, that makes some sense to somebody ;)

Kind regards,

Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you expect that you can have two applications that take different kinds of inputs that share the same components that handle input?  At best you can have "skinny" controllers, pushing most of the logic into the model.  The difference between web and desktop application implementations of MVC are very significant, especially with respect to the couplings between views and controllers.  I don't really see how you could simply swap out views between web/desktop applications.

On the other hand it is very possible, to swap between different types of views within the same basic platform.  For example, you could easily have both standard and mobile web views for the same application.  Changing out just the views is both possible and, likely, preferable to other methods of making standard and mobile versions of an application available.

Comment: right, that makes sense to me. so, at best, I could go for some over freighted controllers, that could satisfy all possible needs (but sounds whacky) or maybe not so skinny controllers to keep the logic out of the model and add kind of adapter for the platform-specific operations. anyway, that was a good little puzzle-piece. thnx